# Dual Boot Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD and Windows 10 on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, ssd, acer

I bought an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-42. It came with Windows 10 on the SSD, but my plan was to install Ubuntu 18.04 in the SSD and install Windows 10 in the HDD. This, because my focus for this laptop is coding. I already have a gaming pc.

I'm having several problems:

1. When finishing installing Ubuntu the first time, I had a really hard time booting into Ubuntu, because of some conflicts with the kernel, and reading some posts I figure that adding "pci=noacpi" as a parameter in the boot options it could boot correctly. It did.
2. There is no GRUB. I tried using boot-repair, but it did nothing.
3. I can't see the Windows 10 partition installed in the HDD.
4. Ubuntu doesn't let me install new drivers. The touchpad is disabled, even with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

I'm considering starting all over again, but I would like to do it correctly. I'm still not sure if having both OS separated in both drives is the right way, and haven't found a step-by-step for my laptop model.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I guess you have to clarify a few things.  What does "there is no grub" mean?  The grub menu is usually not shown.  So, you have to configure it to show (with usually a short time delay).  Or, is grub (the boot loader and not its menu) non-existent?  As for #3, what is on the HDD, then?  Perhaps you can use an Ubuntu boot disk and run `gparted` to see if you still have data on the HDD.  i.e., did you erase it by accident.  Boot-repair's report can also tell you this.

Comment: Unless you're out of patience, I guess you can look into fixing this instead of starting all over.  If you did the latter, you might end up repeating what you did before.  Many people have placed two OS', one on an SSD and another on an HDD.  I'm sure you can look at past posts from others on this site before you panic.  Don't worry about finding instructions for your exact model; it doesn't have to be exact.

Comment: With two drives, often better to turn off in UEFI one drive or physically disconnect it. Did you see these? [SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42 Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 &

Answer (score 0):

what I suggest you do is to have a single unit where to install the operating systems.
So choose whether to use an SSD or an HDD, once chosen creates a USB with ubuntu to format the disk and with GParted creates two partitions one for ubuntu and one for windows. Then use the USB with ubuntu to install it (very important to have the UEFI bios), once installed ubuntu go to this link (https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php) to download the version of windows that you interest. Create the key with Windows 10 from ubuntu using UNetbootin. Once the USB has been created with Windows, start the computer from that USB key and when it asks you where to install windows choose the partition for windows 10 created previously with GParted. Once installed Windows 10 restart your computer and you should see the grub.

I hope I have helped you

Comment: Maybe "ad-guard" is fine and good, idk, never heard of the site. It shows no SHA1 for the current Windows 10 version; i don't like that. It has Chinese Windows too; i don't like that. I personally would download the Windows ISO from microsoft not ad-guard.